# How to set the maxTimeMS for a bulk_write operation?

Tags: python, mongodb, timeout, pymongo

I get a lot of pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout when using bulk_write with a list of updates. I can't find the timeout duration nor how to change it.

collection.bulk_write(operationslist, ordered = False, maxTimeMS = 0) doesn't work (unexpected keyword)

How can i set it? Or a parameter on collection (or connection) level, to avoid timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, bulkWrite sets the timeout via the writeConcern property, e.g.

```
 db.test.bulkWrite(
      [
         { updateMany :
            ... 

         },
         ...
      ],
      { writeConcern : { w : "majority", wtimeout : 100 } }
   );
```

so I imagine the pymongo driver will be similar. I'm not a Python dev but maybe:

```
coll = db.get_collection('test', write_concern=WriteConcern(w=3, wtimeout=1, wtimeout=1000))
coll.bulk_write(...)
```

Comment: Yep, that was the trick, as I found earlier, the write concern cannot be defined at the bulkWrite call, so it should be passed in the get_collection... that's not really ideal though...